# Redirect to Login page when refresh token expires?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I am using an OAuth2 flow to authenticate. The refresh token is valid for a day. I am confused that will the provider will redirect the user to login page each day or do I have to do that by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be coded in your UI, when the first API call is made the next day, which will result in a 401 error being returned due to an expired token.

The important coding point is that as a UI client you need to expect 401 responses from the API when either the token or user session expires.

- When you get a 401 from the API, try to get a new token and retry the API call
- If the token refresh fails, redirect the end user to sign in again

Of course it is your responsibility to ensure that the end user never experiences errors.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

- [API Client Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts)
- [Code to Get a Token](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Blog Post on User Session](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/24/spa-and-api-final-http-messages/)

Comment: Which protocol are you trying to follow ? I guess you are talking about the first token, that is just a step for you to get the user token. The average user token last months, but you will have to renew it yourself for better user experience.

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/refresh-token for refreshing token. Will that do the trick...